# Ubuntu20: nothing happens when I try to run Anaconda install script

Tags: bash, anaconda, sh

I have downloaded the current version of Anaconda to my Downloads folder. In Terminal I CD’d to the folder and tried

```
bash Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Nothing happens except that a fresh prompt appears.
I have tried

```
sh Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

Nothing. I tried

```
chmod +x Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

followed by

```
./Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

and got nothing.

I have done all these things with sudo, as well. I used ls-l to verify that the file was present, I was the owner and execute was set. I am using a 2day old version of Ubuntu20 Fossa with most defaults unchanged. Is this a settings change issue? All the articles I have seen so far list the methods I have already tried.

Edit: per request, here's the first part of the bash -x output, up to the EULA. I can provide the rest if needed.(The part at the very bottom, beginning with read -r is something Ubuntu stuck in my cut-and-paste that I can't get rid of.)

- export OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
- OLD_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=
- unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- echo Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
- grep '.sh$'
- '[' -n /bin/bash ']'
- RUNNING_SHELL=/bin/bash
- '[' -z /bin/bash ']'
- '[' '!' -f /bin/bash ']'
- '[' -z /bin/bash ']'
- '[' '!' -f /bin/bash ']'
  +++ dirname Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
  ++ DIRNAME=.
  ++ cd .
  ++ pwd
- THIS_DIR=/home/jrw/Downloads
  ++ basename Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
- THIS_FILE=Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
- THIS_PATH=/home/jrw/Downloads/Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh
- PREFIX=/root/anaconda3
- BATCH=0
- FORCE=0
- SKIP_SCRIPTS=0
- TEST=0
- REINSTALL=0
- USAGE='
  usage: Anaconda3-2020.07-Linux-x86_64.sh [options]

Installs Anaconda3 2020.07

-b           run install in batch mode (without manual intervention),
it is expected the license terms are agreed upon
-f           no error if install prefix already exists
-h           print this help message and exit
-p PREFIX    install prefix, defaults to /root/anaconda3, must not contain spaces.
-s           skip running pre/post-link/install scripts
-u           update an existing installation
-t           run package tests after installation (may install conda-build)
'

- which getopt
  ++ getopt bfhp:sut ''
- OPTS=' -- '
- '[' '!' 0 ']'
- eval set -- ' -- '
  ++ set -- --
- true
- case "$1" in
- shift
- break
- '[' 0 = 0 ']'
  ++ uname -m
- '[' x86_64 '!=' x86_64 ']'
  ++ uname
- '[' Linux '!=' Linux ']'
- printf '\n'
- printf 'Welcome to Anaconda3 2020.07\n'
  Welcome to Anaconda3 2020.07
- printf '\n'
- printf 'In order to continue the installation process, please review the license\n'
  In order to continue the installation process, please review the license
- printf 'agreement.\n'
  agreement.
- printf 'Please, press ENTER to continue\n'
  Please, press ENTER to continue
- printf '>>> '

> > > - read -r dummy

- pager=cat
- command -v more
- pager=more
- more

Comment: It's probably running into an error and suppressing the output.  Before you execute bash, issue "set -x"  and provide the output.

Comment: Execute the script with `bash -x`.

Comment: This is the bash -x result, up to the EULA. If you need the rest, I can post it.